# Can't upload image to folder

Tags: php, file-upload

Trying to let users upload images to a folder and view it but It won't 
work. I have a way so people can upload their profile pic but it won't let them upload to there gallery. Below is the code for it. The error i'm getting is that the file won't create a file and upload the image to that folder like so... user/robbie/myself/94399549904fkfkmkd.png

```
if (isset($_FILES["photo"]["name"]) && isset($_POST["gallery"])){
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM photos WHERE user='$log_username'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
if($row[0] > 14){
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=The demo system allows only 15 pictures total");
    exit(); 
}
$gallery = $_POST["gallery"];

    $target_dir = "/user/$log_username/$gallery/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["photo"]["name"]). " has been   uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
```

This is the form for the users

```
$photo_form  = '<form id="photo_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="photo_system.php?gallery=yes">';
$photo_form .=   '<h3>Hi '.$u.', add a new photo into one of your galleries</h3>';
$photo_form .=   '<b>Choose Gallery:</b> ';
$photo_form .=   '<select name="gallery" required>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value=""></option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Myself">Myself</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Family">Family</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Pets">Pets</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Friends">Friends</option>';
$photo_form .=     '<option value="Random">Random</option>';
$photo_form .=   '</select>';
$photo_form .=   ' &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>Choose Photo:</b> ';
$photo_form .=   '<input type="file" name="photo" required>';
$photo_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload Photo Now"></p>';
$photo_form .= '</form>';
```

Comment: what errors are you getting and where's the form for this? Too many unknowns.

Comment: btw, you're probably outputting before header here and your logic is off.

Comment: The error i'm getting is that the file won't create a file and upload the image to that folder like so... user/robbie/myself/94399549904fkfkmkd.png

Comment: most likely a permissions issue and a path issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've encountered similar problems in the past it's usually been related to either the directory that you are moving the file to not existing, or the user php is running as not having the required permissions to write to that location.

First I would make sure that the '/user' folder exists and that the user php is running as can write to it. A temporary fix, if you are running on Linux might be to set the permissions on that folder to 777 (anyone can read and write it) using the command below:

```
chmod 777 /user
```

This will help rule out php write permissions as the problem when troubleshooting, however shouldn't be used as a long term solution. Instead the owner of the /user folder should be set to whichever user php is running as, then the permissions set to 755, which only allows that user to write to that location.

Also, bear in mind that starting a path with a / will look in the root of your file system. If the folder is in your website directory, you might need the full absolute path. For example /var/www/user.

To help find this out, it might help to use the getcwd() function in php:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Next, make sure you are creating the directories before writing to them.

1. Check that the directory exists using is_dir():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

2. Create the directory if required using mkdir():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

You will likely need to do the above steps at both username (/user/$log_username) and gallery (/user/$log_username/$gallery) level.